# CUDA - Kernel uses more registers than expected?

Tags: c++, cuda

I have a kernel, which calculates sums. If i go through the kernel counting the number of variables declared, i would assume a total of 5 registers per kernel*. However when profiling the kernel, 34 registers are used. I need get down to 30 register to allow the execution of 1024 threads.

Can anybody see what is wrong?

```
__global__ void sum_kernel(float* values, float bk_size, int start_idx, int end_idx, int resolution, float* avgs){

    // Allocate shared memory (assuming a maximum of 1024 threads).
    __shared__ float sums[1024];

    // Boundary check.
    if(blockIdx.x == 0){
        avgs[blockIdx.x] = values[start_idx];
        return;
    }
    else if(blockIdx.x == resolution-1) {
        avgs[blockIdx.x] = values[start_idx+(end_idx-start_idx)-1];
        return;
    }
    else if(blockIdx.x > resolution -2){
        return;
    }

    // Iteration index calculation.
    unsigned int idx_prev = floor((blockIdx.x + 0) * bk_size) + 1;
    unsigned int from = idx_prev + threadIdx.x*(bk_size / blockDim.x);
    unsigned int to = from + (bk_size / blockDim.x);
    to = (to < (end_idx-start_idx))? to : (end_idx-start_idx);

    // Partial average calculation using shared memory.
    sums[threadIdx.x] = 0;
    for (from; from < to; from++)
    {
        sums[threadIdx.x] += values[from+start_idx];
    }

    __syncthreads();

    // Addition of partial sums.
    if(threadIdx.x != 0) return;
    from = 1;
    for(from; from < 1024; from++)
    {
        sum += sums[from];
    }
    avgs[blockIdx.x] = sum;
}
```

- Assuming 2 registers per pointer, 1 register per unsigned int, arguments stored in constant memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot estimate the number of used registers in terms of the number of declared variables. The compiler can use registers to make address calculations or to store temporary variables you are not explicitly declaring etc.

For example, I have disassembled the first part of your kernel function, namely

```
__global__ void sum_kernel(float* values, float bk_size, int start_idx, int end_idx, int resolution, float* avgs){

    // Boundary check.
    if(blockIdx.x == 0){
        avgs[blockIdx.x] = values[start_idx];
        return;
    }
    else if(blockIdx.x == resolution-1) {
        avgs[blockIdx.x] = values[start_idx+(end_idx-start_idx)-1];
        return;
    }
    else if(blockIdx.x > resolution -2){
        return;
    }
}
```

having the following result

```
code for sm_20
       Function : _Z10sum_kernelPffiiiS_
.headerflags    @"EF_CUDA_SM20 EF_CUDA_PTX_SM(EF_CUDA_SM20)"
/*0000*/        MOV R1, c[0x1][0x100];            /* 0x2800440400005de4 */   R1 = [0x1][0x100]
/*0008*/        S2R R2, SR_CTAID.X;               /* 0x2c00000094009c04 */   R2 = BlockIdx.x
/*0010*/        MOV R0, c[0x0][0x34];             /* 0x28004000d0001de4 */   R0 = [0x0][0x34]
/*0018*/        ISETP.EQ.AND P0, PT, R2, RZ, PT;  /* 0x190e0000fc21dc23 */   if (R2 == 0)
/*0020*/    @P0 BRA 0x78;                         /* 0x40000001400001e7 */
/*0028*/        MOV R0, c[0x0][0x30];             /* 0x28004000c0001de4 */   
/*0030*/        IADD R0, R0, -0x1;                /* 0x4800fffffc001c03 */
/*0038*/        ISETP.NE.AND P0, PT, R2, R0, PT;  /* 0x1a8e00000021dc23 */
/*0040*/    @P0 EXIT ;                            /* 0x80000000000001e7 */
/*0048*/        MOV R0, c[0x0][0x2c];             /* 0x28004000b0001de4 */
/*0050*/        ISCADD R2, R2, c[0x0][0x34], 0x2; /* 0x40004000d0209c43 */
/*0058*/        ISCADD R0, R0, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2; /* 0x4000400080001c43 */
/*0060*/        LDU R0, [R0+-0x4];                /* 0x8bfffffff0001c85 */
/*0068*/        ST [R2], R0;                      /* 0x9000000000201c85 */
/*0070*/        BRA 0x98;                         /* 0x4000000080001de7 */
/*0078*/        MOV R2, c[0x0][0x28];             /* 0x28004000a0009de4 */   
/*0080*/        ISCADD R2, R2, c[0x0][0x20], 0x2; /* 0x4000400080209c43 */   
/*0088*/        LDU R2, [R2];                     /* 0x8800000000209c85 */   R2 used for addressing and storing gmem data
/*0090*/        ST [R0], R2;                      /* 0x9000000000009c85 */   R0 used for addressing
/*0098*/        EXIT ;                            /* 0x8000000000001de7 */
```

In the CUDA code snippet above, there is no explicitly declared variable. As you can see from the disassembled code, the compiler has used `3` registers, namely, `R0`, `R1` and `R2`. Those registers are interchanbeble in functionality and used to store constants, memory addresses and global memory values.

Comment: Small correction: predicates are not stored in R-registers, but predicate registers (P0 in this case).

Comment: @njuffa Thank you very much. I have immediately fixed the last sentence of the answer.